# Java Error When Enter To Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I Install JDK , JRE , SDK , Eclipse Last Version .

When I Enter The Eclipse Show Me This Error .

Error

```
---------------------------
Eclipse
---------------------------
An error has occurred.  See the log file
e:\Learn\Android\Tools\ADT - SDK - Eclipse - JRE (x64)\eclipse-java-mars-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\1450631150720.log
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

And Log File Error

```
!SESSION Sun Dec 20 20:35:50 IRST 2015 -----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2015-12-20 20:35:50.886
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.0.v20140403-1907.jar
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2015-12-20 20:35:50.901
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: Eclipse is no longer supported for Android development.

Comment: @cricket_007 not entirely true. Certainly, Google went for IntelliJ, but there are people still working on Android tooling in Eclipse, see https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore